# Drop rows based on column value (Dask)

Tags: python, dask, series

I want to drop certain rows of a Dask DataFrame based on the value of a column.

I've had no problems in the past doing this:

```
ddf = ddf[ (ddf['col'] == str1) | (ddf['col'] == str2)]
```

What I have now is a little different.
This column contains a string like 'abc,def,ghk' and I want to drop it if it doesn't contain 'abc' or 'doh'.

I've tried stuff like:

```
 ddf = ddf[ ('abc' in ddf['col']) | ('doh' in ddf['col'])]
```

But I get

```
 KeyError: True
```

(I think) because the expression returns a bool and there's no key with that value,

And

```
 ddf = ddf.drop(ddf.index[('abc' in ddf['col']) | ('doh' in ddf['col'])])
```

which gives me

```
 NotImplementedError: Series getitem in only supported for other series objects with matching partition structure
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'abc' in ddf['col']` looks to see if the string `'abc'` is *anywhere* in the column, and returns a single value.  If you want two arrays to slice the DataFrame with, use this instead:

```
 ddf = ddf[ (ddf['col'].str.isin('abc')) | (ddf['col'].str.isin('doh'))]
```

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear :)